# How can I get a text from a div?

Tags: javascript, html, fetch

I'm trying to get a piece of text that is inside a `<div class>` of a especific URL and return only the content inside the `<a title>`. Like `"<div class="test"><a title="Hello World"></a></div>"` and return `Hello World`.
But I don't know what should do to return pieces of the text, it's returning whole html.

```
const fetch = require("node-fetch");
fetch('https://www.google.com/')
    .then(function (response) {
        switch (response.status) {
            // status "OK"
            case 200:
                return response.text();
            // status "Not Found"
            case 404:
                throw response;
        }
    })
    .then(function (template) {
        console.log(template)
        console.log("DONE");
    })
    .catch(function (response) {
        // "Not Found"
        console.log(response.statusText);
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
        

        fetch('https://www.myear.sg/test.php')
        .then(function (response) {
            switch (response.status) {
                // status "OK"
                case 200:
                    return response.text();
                // status "Not Found"
                case 404:
                    throw response;
            }
        })
        .then(function (template) {
            console.log(find_id_details (template))
           document.getElementById("abc").innerHTML = find_id_details (template)
        })
        .catch(function (response) {
            // "Not Found"
            console.log(response.statusText);
        });




        function find_id_details (input){
            var part1 = input.split('<div id="abcd">')[1];
            var part2 = part1.split('"></a>')[0];
            var part3 = part2.split('<a title="').pop()
            return part3
        }
```

```html
<div id="abc"> after the processing , you will get the answer </div>
```

You can check this answer :

your issue was : **"But I don't know what should do to return pieces of the text, it's returning whole html."**

lets assunme your html file is :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
   <meta charset="UTF-8">
   <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
   <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
   <div id="abcd"> <a title="Hello World"></a></div>
   <div > test 2 </div>
   <div > test 3 </div>
</body>
</html>
```

now you will get the whole html as your response . and you want to parse the HTMl text and want to get the  tag title "Hello World":

I make a custom function to parse the input HTML. now I have no idea about your HTML file.
please check the **find_id_details()** function .

in your code , at the place of **console.log(template)** , use **console.log(find_id_details (template))**

```
fetch('https://example.com/something')
    .then(function (response) {
        switch (response.status) {
            // status "OK"
            case 200:
                return response.text();
            // status "Not Found"
            case 404:
                throw response;
        }
    })
    .then(function (template) {
        console.log(find_id_details (template))
    })
    .catch(function (response) {
        // "Not Found"
        console.log(response.statusText);
    });




    function find_id_details (input){
        var part1 = input.split('<div id="abcd">')[1];
        var part2 = part1.split('"></a>')[0];
        var part3 = part2.split('<a title="').pop()
        return part3
    }
```

Comment: thanks for the answer !! For some reason it's returning as undefined the part1,part2,part3

Comment: I added the live code also, you can check that. I upload the code in my own server and now you can check that.  can you share your HTML code or the link? as the function totally depends on the structure of the HTML file.   if the answer is helpful please upvote. thanks

Comment: if your HTML file is different than that of mine sample HTML, then the code may not work and give undefined as a result.

Comment: thank you a lot!! As soon I get 15 reputation I will upvote. I'm learning a lot with your help.

Comment: I will upvote you for your kind attitude ... smile.

Answer (score 1):

This should do it:

```
fetch('https://github.com/')
    .then(res => res.text())
    .then(body => console.log(body));
```

Taken from node-fetch documentation https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-fetch

Or if you want to specifically get the title tag, you may use:

```
 var titleTag = body.split('<title>')[1].split('</title>')[0];
```

Comment: thank you. This is good. I'm just thinking how What you think I should do for getting more than one elements?

Comment: That all remains the same. Anything from the body can be fetched like this. So, say, this time you want to get <p> tag: 


var paraTag = body.split('<p>')[1].split('</p>')[0];

Answer (score 1):

if you want to manipulate string HTML, you have first convert it to HTML object (or parse the string). You can do it this way:

```js
var htmlString = '<div class="test"><a title="Hello World"></a></div>';
var temp = document.createElement('div');
temp.innerHTML = htmlString;
var htmlObject = temp.firstChild;

console.log(htmlObject.getElementsByTagName("a")[0].getAttribute("title"))

//Get attribute from all elements by tag

var text = '<div class="test"><a title="Hello World"><a title="Hello Street"></a></a><a title="Hello City"></a></div>';

function getAttributeFromAllElementsByTag(htmlString, tag, attribute){
  var tempArray = [];
  var temp = document.createElement('div');
  temp.innerHTML = htmlString;
  var htmlObject = temp.firstChild;
  var arrayOfElements = htmlObject.getElementsByTagName(tag);
  for(var i = 0;i < arrayOfElements.length;i++){
    tempArray.push(arrayOfElements[i].getAttribute(attribute))
  }
  return tempArray
}

console.log(getAttributeFromAllElementsByTag(text, "a", "title"))
```

Comment: thank you for helping me. Could you help me with this please? Then I try to type node file.js to open I get an error `var temp = document.createElement('div');
           ^
ReferenceError: document is not defined` For some reason I cant open it in my editor